# add javascript button to order place button

Tags: plugin-development

I'm want to add confirm popup in checkout page if user select credit card gateway.
I success to add javascript code after click on "place order" button using:

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    $("form.woocommerce-checkout").on('submit', function () {

        // show confirm popup and conditions to continue or return to form.

    });

});
```

it's work, but in backgroud the page continue to redirect to place order.
how can I stop the redirect? and how can I make redirect after user click on OK in the confirm popup?

Answer (score 2):

the first step is to define the event in doing this for the function

```
.on('submit', function (event) {
```

and after you can stop the form submit with this code :

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_button_html', 'custom_order_button_html');
function custom_order_button_html( $button ) {

    // The text of the button
    $order_button_text = __('Place order', 'woocommerce');

    // HERE your Javascript Event
    $js_event = "fbq('track', 'AddPaymentInfo');";

    // HERE you make changes (Replacing the code of the button):
    $button = '<input type="submit" onClick="'.$js_event.'" class="button alt" name="woocommerce_checkout_place_order" id="place_order" value="' . esc_attr( $order_button_text ) . '" data-value="' . esc_attr( $order_button_text ) . '" />';

    return $button;
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are not an acceptable. You need to explain how the given code solves the issue and where it's added.